# IDEA Docker run target. ClassNotFound

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I am trying to run simple hello-world project on docker run target.

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfrDq.png)

I have used that guide
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/run-targets-run-and-debug-your-app-in-the-desired-environment/

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OzlT.png)

I used openjdk:19 image and other autoconfig.

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDikh.png)

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmtf4.png)

I see that somebody in comments has the same problems. Maybe somebody knows how to solve it.

I have tried to change path in some places. But i see that it creates directory foe

```
/usr/java/openjdk-19/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath **/tmp/f3d49c60-d915-4e17-a562-e109d17ca5b5** org.example.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think it is some problems with copying target directory to docker container

Comment: Try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-java-app-in-a-container.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder. Yes, it works fine. But I want to use debug. And when I am using runing in container and connecting to remote jvm for debug it says that in next version it will be not aviliable and i need to use run targets. I am trying to use Run Targets but there are so little information about Run Targets.